# convex envelope in integral form

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, functional-calculus

Take any function $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$. The convex hull of $f$ can be defined as

$$
f^{**} := \sup\{g \text{ is convex }: g(x) \leq f(x)\;\forall x\}.
$$

One way to find this is to take the limit of $p\to\infty$ of the following problem
$$
f^{**}(x) = \min_{\theta}\left\{\sum_{i=1}^p \theta_i f(z_i) : \sum_{i=1}^p \theta_i z_i = x, \;\theta_i\geq 0,\; \sum_{i=1}^p \theta_i = 1\right\}.
$$

I'd like to write this statement in integral form, but I'm struggling, and for some reason I can't seem to find a reference.

Best so far from  comments:
$$
f^{**}(x) = \min_\mu\left\{\int_{\mathrm{dom} f} f(\mu) d \mu : \int_{\mathrm{dom} f} \mu d \mu = x\right\}.
$$

Comment: your sum should have $z$ under "min", and the integral does not need a $z$

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I think you're right that that $z$ should not be there, but it's confusing to me because the discretization is in $\mu$ but the integral is taken over the values taken by $z$. It doesn't feel like $\mu$ and $z$ live in the same domain.

Comment: the $z_i$ are the points with positive measure in the sum-definition, but that is already fully captured by $\mu$ in the integral-definition

Comment: ok, this looks reasonable. but under min it should not have z, now that z is eliminated, no?